# How does std::list allocate nodes vs. elements

Tags: c++, allocator, stdlist

How does `std::list` allocate the nodes in which it keeps the `next`/`prev` pointers and the `T` element it contains?

I think that standard allocators can only be used to allocate memory for one type (because `std::allocator::allocate` allocates memory in increments of `sizeof(T)`). So it seems impossible to allocate the list node and the contained object in a single allocation, which means that the nodes have to be allocated with whatever the implementation decides, and the nodes store pointers to the objects instead of the objects themselves, and this implies two levels of indirection to get from a pointer to a list node to the object it contains, which seems inefficient. Is this the case?

Comment: What prevents you from having a Node structure with both pointers and a `T` as a member ?

Comment: @Quentin because the template argument to the allocator that `std::list` uses is the same type as the list stores, not a `node` structure. This is the reason for my question.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Good question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The allocator has a member template class, rebind, which is responsible for allocating other types. The page for `std::allocator` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) actually has an example of the exact thing you are asking. I will quote it here:

until C++11

> `std::list<T, A>` allocates nodes of some internal type `Node<T>`, using
>   the allocator `A::rebind<Node<T>>::other`

since C++11

> `std::list<T, A>` allocates nodes of some internal type `Node<T>`, using
>   the allocator `std::allocator_traits<A>::rebind_alloc<Node<T>>`, which
>   is implemented in terms of `A::rebind<Node<T>>::other` if A is an
>   `std::allocator`

Comment: Oh wow, I should have read that page more thoroughly before I asked.  Thanks.

Comment: This means that the allocator given to `list`, the one which allocates `T`s, is never used, correct?

Comment: @asdf: That's up to the implementation. But in the case of the most obvious implementation, as far as I can tell, that is correct.

Comment: `std::allocator` page says rebind is deprecated in c++17 and removed in c++20, so how does it work the latest versions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38565365/why-did-stdallocator-lose-member-types-functions-in-c17