# Why did std::allocator lose member types/functions in C++17?

Tags: c++, memory-management, stl, allocator, c++17

While looking at [std::allocator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator), I see that members:
`value_type`,
`pointer`,
`const_pointer`,
`reference`,
`const_reference`,
`size_type`,
`difference_type`, and
`rebind` have all been deprecated.

Allocators will also no longer have the members:
 `address`,  `max_size`,  `construct`, or `destroy`.

Why did this happen?  Did it have something to do with polymophic allocators?

Comment: The first set of members look like they really make sense for containers, not allocators. I believe that there's a `std::addressof` now to replace address(). Who needs max_size anyway; and the rest should be replaceable by placement new/explicit destructor invocation.

Comment: There is now also an [`allocator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits) that will fill in the missing parts.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you look at [the relevant isocpp paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0174r1.html#2.2) you can see that the first set you mention is now thought to be better placed in [`std::allocator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits). Since the STL (not even standard library) came out, there's been more of a shift to use traits.

`rebind` is also a relic. When the STL first came out, aliases and template-template parameters were not supported. With these language features in existence, `rebind` seems fairly convoluted. E.g., as you can see in [an answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362363/why-is-allocatorrebind-necessary-when-we-have-template-template-parameters), in The C++ Programming Language, 4th edition, section 34.4.1, p. 998, commenting the 'classical' rebind member in default allocator class :

```
template<typename U>
     struct rebind { using other = allocator<U>;};
```

Bjarne Stroustupr writes this : "The curious rebind template is an archaic alias. It should have been:

```
template<typename U>
using other = allocator<U>;
```

However, allocator was defined before such aliases were supported by C++."

So, altogether, it's the standard library catching up with the language and paradigm shifts.