# How do I not call a constructor of an object that is located in a node of a linked list?

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list, nodes

So I have a class, lets call it Cow. This cow has an age and some other variables like a static number of Cows alive variable.

Well I want to make a linked list, and I made the class for it and the node structure inside of the linkedlist class, looks a bit like this.

```
struct node{
        Cow data;
        node* next;
};
```

Then there's my addNode function to add a node.

```
void List::addNode(Cow newData)
{
    //Creates a Cow object that will skew counters. BELOW.
    node* n = new node;
    n->data = newData;
    n->next = NULL;
    if(head == NULL){
        head = n;
    }else{
        curr = head;
        while(curr->next != NULL){
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        curr->next = n;
    }

}
```

With the line 
    node* n = new node, it'll create a new Cow object, which calls the Cow constructor, which increments the number of Cows alive static variable.

Simply, my question is...
How would I go about not calling the constructor for that Cow object when the node is first created, so I can fill it up with the newData object instead. Therefore not messing up my counter, which increments in the constructor?

Comment: Why would you not want to increment the _"number of Cows"_ counter. 
`new node` will create "new" _"`Cows`"_, isn't ?

Comment: Constructors are always called. You can use more than one constuctor as well. I recommend having an empty constructor that does nothing

Comment: If the police is not around, you can do some "cheating" and borrow `malloc` from cousin `C` then invoke in-pace construction where needed. Unlike `new`, `malloc` does not invoke the constructor. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a `node` constructor which takes a `Cow` parameter and uses it to copy-construct its internal `Cow`. I assume `Cow`'s copy constructor doesn't increment the static counter.

```
struct node{
    node(Cow &cow): data(cow) {}    

    Cow data;
    node* next;
};
```

Comment: And since cows are big, it makes sense to rather `move` them than to copy them.  `node(Cow &&cow): data(std::move(cow)){}`

Comment: Might be interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24974935/how-does-stdlist-allocate-nodes-vs-elements

Answer (score 0):

What you may want is *moving* your object into the list.  That way, you won't have more 'live' objects than needed.

You can accomplish this the simplest way by separating the `Cow` from the `Node` by e.g. wrapping it inside an `std::unique_ptr<Cow>`.  You get all the correctness for free.

The other way is to only allow *moving* cows into your list:

```
List::addNode(Cow &&cow) {
    auto node = new node(std::move(cow));
    ...
}
```

But then you'll also need to add a move constructor to `Cow`, which obviously does not increment the counter:

```
Cow::Cow(Cow &&other)
  : field1(std::move(other.field1))
  , field2(std::move(other.field2))
{ // dont increment counter! 
   other.dontDecrementCounterOnDestruction(); // important!
}
```

An extra possibility is to actually 'emplace' your cow onto the list (like `std::emplace_back()`):

```
template<typename T...>
void List::addNode(T... arguments) {
  auto n = new node(arguments...);
  ...
};

template<typename T...>
node::node(T... arguments): myCow(arguments...)
{ // ... whatever else needs to be done 
}
```

But then you're getting *very* close to what `std::list` does, and unless it's an exercise, you'll better be of just using `std::list` or `std::forward_list` anyway.

Answer (score -1):

> How would I go about not calling the constructor for that Cow object when the node is first created,

You can't do that. When you construct a `node` object, all of its member variables will be initialized. With `node` being defined the way it is and if `Cow` has a default constructor, then it will be called to initialize `data`.

> so I can fill it up with the `newData` object instead.

The best you can do is use a move constructor or a copy constructor to avoid the cost of construction followed by assignment.

Update `node` to:

```
struct node{

   node() : data(), next(nullptr) {}

   node(Cow const& copy) : data(copy), next(nullptr) {}

        Cow data;
        node* next;
};
```

and then update `addNode` to:

```
void List::addNode(Cow newData)
{
   node* n = new node(newData);
   if(head == NULL){
      head = n;
   }else{
      curr = head;
      while(curr->next != NULL){
         curr = curr->next;
      }
      curr->next = n;
   }
}
```

Comment: "you can't do that".  How is it done in `std::list`?

Comment: @xtofl, Are you saying that if you use a `std::list` instead of your own list, the constructor doesn't get called when you add an item to the list?

Comment: Almost: the `T` is _allocated_ together with the rest of the node, but is constructed _in place_ afterwards.

Comment: You can allocate memory for a `node` using `malloc` and then construct the `T` in place by using a placement `new` operator. It's hard for me to tell whether the standard library you are using is relying on that technique. Regardless, the constructor of `T` will  be called when the placement `new` operator gets called. Ultimately, in your case, `data` needs to be initialized as a `Cow` object. If you have user defined constructors, you may use any of them to initialize `data`.  But if you have at least one user defined constructor, a constructor has to be called to initialize `data`.

Comment: I'm most known with the MSVC included stl.  But regardless, I was negating the assumption that it can't be done.

Comment: Using `node* ptr = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));` is not exactly constructing a `node`.